# what is the cause of getting 'sigbrt' error here?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, tree-traversal

The question: 

"Connect Nodes at Same Level
Given a binary tree, connect the nodes that are at same level. You'll be given an addition nextRight pointer for the same.

Initially, all the nextRight pointers point to garbage values. Your function should set these pointers to point next right for each node."


My strategy:

1. perform level order traversal
2. store all elements in a vector
3. to signify change in level add nullptr to vector
4. iterate vector and make current nodes nextRight pointer field contain the value of the i+1 th element

My output:
Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorAbort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)

My code(of function only):

```
/*struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
    struct Node* nextRight;
}; */

void connect(Node *root)
{
   // vector of all node addresses
   // for each set nxtrt next ele
   // in level order add a nullptr after each level as delimiter
   queue<Node*>q;
   if(root)
   {
       q.push(root);
       q.push(nullptr);
   }
   vector<Node*>v;
   Node *curr;
   while(!q.empty())
   {
       curr = q.front();
       q.pop();
       v.push_back(curr);
       if(curr == nullptr)
       {
           q.push(curr);
           continue;
       }
       if(curr->left)
       {
           q.push(curr->left);
       }
       if(curr->right)
       {
           q.push(curr->right);
       }
   }
   
   for(int i = 0; i < (int)(v.size() - 1); ++i)
   {
       v[i]->nextRight = v[i+1]; //making each node point to right node
   }
}
```

I have tried to find out where this error is coming from but was unable to find it.
What is the reason for such an output?

Comment: Would you please post a minimal, complete, verifieable example? (What's the definition of Node, how do you call `connect`?)

Comment: q.push(nullptr); this might not be safe for stl containers. try without pushing nullptr version of code.

Comment: @IS oh, but why isnt it safe?

Comment: @JCWasmx86 hi! i posted the Node structure as for connect, thats not necessary to know because just assume that the binary tree is already made and the pointer to root node is passed to the function specified above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build some executable where you actually use `connect` with -g, eg. `$ g++ node.cpp -g`, then run it using `gdb`: `$ gdb a.out`. Once you get an exception, type `bt full` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html). This will show you exactly where the error is. Tried to prepare some minimal example (though it's not your usecase, I believe):

```
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
    struct Node* nextRight;
};

void connect(Node *root)
{
   // vector of all node addresses
   // for each set nxtrt next ele
   // in level order add a nullptr after each level as delimiter
   queue<Node*>q;
   if(root)
   {
       q.push(root);
       q.push(nullptr);
   }
   vector<Node*>v;
   Node *curr;
   while(!q.empty())
   {
       curr = q.front();
       q.pop();
       v.push_back(curr);
       if(curr == nullptr)
       {
           q.push(curr);
           continue;
       }
       if(curr->left)
       {
           q.push(curr->left);
       }
       if(curr->right)
       {
           q.push(curr->right);
       }
   }
   
   for(int i = 0; i < (int)(v.size() - 1); ++i)
   {
       v[i]->nextRight = v[i+1]; //making each node point to right node
   }
}

int main() {
Node t;
t.data = 5;
connect(&t);
return 0;
}
```

Error I got:

```
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/mpiotrowski/KeyTestSpyro/PiecewiseQuadratic/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554b17 in connect (root=0x7fffffffdd50) at test2.cpp:36
36         if(curr->left)
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000555555554b17 in connect (root=0x7fffffffdd50) at test2.cpp:36
#1  0x0000555555554c79 in main () at test2.cpp:55
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x0000555555554b17 in connect (root=0x7fffffffdd50) at test2.cpp:36
        q = std::queue wrapping: std::deque with 2 elements = {0x20ce2d8d48550020, 0x0}
        v = std::vector of length 5, capacity 8 = {0x7fffffffdd50, 0x0, 0x555555556c70 <__libc_csu_init>, 0x0, 0x20ce258d4c544155}
        curr = 0x20ce258d4c544155
#1  0x0000555555554c79 in main () at test2.cpp:55
        t = {data = 5, left = 0x0, right = 0x555555556c70 <__libc_csu_init>, nextRight = 0x555555554910 <_start>}
```

So, basing on `36         if(curr->left)` we could judge that `curr` is NULL and you are trying to de-reference it in some circumstances.

**Important** just a hint: if you don't feel comfortable with debugger, you could always add `print` in every line and see which print you are missing. You'd be able to identify line with possible error.

Answer (score 1):

First problem is you are recursively adding nullptr to queue so queue will never be empty. You should not push curr if it is nullptr

```
if(curr == nullptr)
   {
       q.push(curr);  // remove this line
       continue;
   }
```

Second problem is you are pushing uninitialized pointers to the queue

```
q.push(curr->left);
```

than next cycle trying to access its  members

```
// where curr pushed as curr->left previous cycle
if(curr->left)
```

give default value to pointer members will be solution

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* left = nullptr;
    struct Node* right = nullptr;
    struct Node* nextRight = nullptr;
};
```